# C++ fread bytesread length not match the length set for function

Tags: android, c++, multithreading

I tried to read a file with fread, it works fine simply using main thread. But when I use other thread to read the file, the returned bytesRead won't match what I requested.

My test code is something like this:

```
FILE* file = fopen(filename.c_str(), "rb");
if (file != nullptr) {
   fseek(file, my_offset, SEEK_SET);
   char buffer[my_length];
   size_t bytesRead = fread(buffer, 1, my_length, file);
```

I checked the file and I'm sure the file is correct, and I've checked the bytesRead for many times and it differs everytime but always smaller than I requested. Simply add another fread for the left data doesn't seem to be correct.

I'm doing this in Android with C++ code if that is relevant.

Any idea would be appreiciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to use multiple threads to read the same file?

Comment: "_But when I use other thread to read the file_": Please show a complete [mre] that demonstrates how exactly you are using threads here.

Comment: "Simply add another fread for the left data doesn't seem to be correct.": Why not?  There are many situations where it is normal for an `fread` to return short, and calling `fread` again is exactly what you should do - loop until you have all of it.    In fact any instance of `fread` that isn't in a loop is likely a bug.  Now, if you read again and the second read fails, then investigating the cause of that failure (check `errno`) will give some indications of what might be happening.

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: There is nothing in the specification of `fread()` (or `read()` for that matter) that says it is obliged to fill the buffer. The behaviour you are experiencing is valid and you have to code defensively for it assuming it can happen, as it is.

Comment: In general, just like POSIX `read()` and `write()`, the C-standard functions _also_ require a loop around them. That’s just the way it is, that’s how the API is specified and, quite often, the library may do truncated (short) reads and writes on purpose when a couple of debugging options are set, to ensure that the code that calls it respects the whole contract. Anyway, _why_ are you using the C standard library with C++? A `std::ifstream` does not have this problem (i.e. it will loop and retry for you somewhere under the hood) and then this question is null and void.

Comment: I kind of fix this by changing from "char buffer[my_length]" to "char* buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * my_length)". Not sure why this worked though.